# OpenAM - SSO J2EE Agent

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

I have a quick question regarding OpenAM. We are thinking of using the auto scale from AWS that allow an instance to be automatically created and deployed in your sever pool if the load requires it.

The only thing that prevents us to do so is that on each instance , we have a j2ee agent that is created with a name (AgentX).

In order to SSO to work, we create this AgentX in the J2EE agent in the OpenAM console.

Is there a way or an API that would allow the creation of an J2EE Agent on OpenAM ? This way we could automate the creation of the agent in OpenAM :)

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You could use ssoadm to create agent profiles, alternatively there is a json/agents endpoint that can be used to create agent profiles if needed.